# Change background color of image in Android

Tags: android, background, imageview

I found allot about changing the background color of an activity but not how to change the backgroundcolor of an imageview, like this as example:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_person_200x200"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:background="#52D017"
            android:padding="1dp" />
```

Anyone?

Comment: `setBackgroundColor` ?

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. The `android:background` attribute (which you have in your example) controls the background of the view. What else do you need?

Answer (score 0):

In your java code, after creating the ImageView object you can try calling the setBackgroundColor() method which is inherited from View. Check out the docs for more info on this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int)

Comment: I tried that, like this but still not working (change bg to red) :        imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(16711680);

Comment: Hmm, did you try passing in a Color rather than that number as mentioned in the other answer? ^^

Answer (score 0):

If adding `android:background` attribute to the `<ImageView>` doesn't work then you should apply it programmatically.

Remove `android:background="#52D017"` from the `<ImageView>` and add the following to your activity file

```
ImageView backgroundImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
backgroundImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(100, 100, 50));
```